# The derivative format of $D^\alpha f$, with $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_d),|\alpha|=n$, $\alpha_i$ is derivatine according to the variable i

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

Let $f_i(x^{'},t)=x_i a(x^{'})e^{a(x^{'})t}, (x^{'},t)=((x_1,x_2,...,x_i,...x_{d-1}),t)\subset \mathbb{R}^{d-1}\times (0,\infty)$

where $a(x^{'},0)=-2\pi i<x,e_d>-\sqrt{\Delta}, \Delta=-4\pi^2<x,e_d>^2+4\pi^2<x,x>,$ with $x=(x',0), <x,y>=x_1y_1+...+x_dy_d, e_d=(0,0,...,1)\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

I need to define the derivative format of $D^\alpha f$, with $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_d),|\alpha|=n$, $\alpha_i$ is derivatine according to the variable i. My purpose is block $|D^\alpha f_i(x^{'},t)|\leq cg(|x^{'}|,t)$, with $c>0$,$g$ somehow but fail, I really need your help, hope you help.

Comment: $$D^\alpha f := (\partial_{x_1})^{\alpha_1}...( \partial_{x_n})^{\alpha_n}f$$

Comment: @s.harp I mean concreteness $D^\alpha f$ from the definition of $f$

Comment: Thats just a large expression with the product formula.